# copied table isn't recognized when I try to select the rows from it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table called 'Vendors' and I copied all of its rows into a newly created tabled called VendorTwo.

```
SELECT *
INTO VendorTwo
FROM Vendors;
```

I know want to look at this new table so I typed

```
SELECT *
FROM VendorTwo
```

But I'm getting an error saying that `Invalid Object Name 'VendorTwo'.' [here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fn43.png)

Comment: Have you created second table ? Create table Vendortwo as (Select * from Vendors) ; then try to Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS caches data model when you connect to a database.

Press SHIFT+CRTL+R to refresh SSMS cache.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, just add more columns. Sometimes sql server give that message if the table its new.

```
create table #vendors(nam varchar(20),age numeric)
create table #vendors2(nam varchar(20),age numeric)

INSERT INTO #vendors VALUES ('Donald Trump',70)
INSERT INTO #vendors VALUES ('Son Goku',35)

INSERT INTO #vendors2
select  * from #vendors
```